# onClick functions run when being changed?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm working on an HTML file that has some buttons with onClick attributes. I've found ways to change the function that runs, but when I change it the new function runs. I've looked at other questions that are similar, but I wasn't able to find an answer.

```js
class buttonController {
  constructor(){
    this.button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
    this.button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
    this.button3 = document.getElementById("button3");
  }

  setButton1(p_func, text){
    this.button1.textContent = text;
    document.getElementById("button1").onclick = p_func; //I've tried using .setAttribute too
  }

  setButton2(p_func, text){
    this.button2.textContent = text;
    document.getElementById("button2").onclick = p_func;
  }

  setButton3(p_func, text){
    this.button3.textContent = text;
    document.getElementById("button3").onclick = p_func;
  }

  detectState(){ //the issue is here. if you set the function to a new function, it will run.
    if (g_state == "COMBAT"){
      this.setButton1(genericFunction(), "Button 1");
      this.setButton2(anotherFunction(), "Button 2");
      this.setButton3(oneMoreFunction(), "Button 3");
    }

    if (g_state == "IDLE"){
      this.setButton1(function(){consoleController.log("button1 pressed");}, "button 1");
      this.setButton2(function(){consoleController.log("button2 pressed");}, "button 2");
      this.setButton3(function(){consoleController.log("button3 pressed");}, "button 3");
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to avoid using jQuery if possible.

Comment: adding a link to a codepen.io would be super helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `setButtonN`, you need to pass in functions without executing them. To fix it, change the way you set the buttons from —

> `this.setButton1(genericFunction(), "Button 1");`

to

> `this.setButton1(genericFunction, "Button 1");`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but then how do I enter arguments?

Comment: you can pass in an anonymous function, like:
`this.setButton1(() => genericFunction(param1, param2), "Button 1")` or `this.setButton1(function() { genericFunction(param1, param2) }, "Button 1")`